# Fullcalendar add startdate and endate manualy

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

This code of fullcalendar for asp works fine.
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar-asp-net/

How to enter or modify manually the startdate and enddate ? (also with a datetime picker)
I try change :

```
$('#addDialog').dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    width: 470,
    buttons: {
        "Add": function () {

            //alert("sent:" + addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "==" + addStartDate.toLocaleString());
            var eventToAdd = {
                title: $("#addEventName").val(),
                description: $("#addEventDesc").val(),
                start: addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                end: addEndDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

            };
```

to

```
$('#addDialog').dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    width: 470,
    buttons: {
        "Add": function () {

            //alert("sent:" + addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "==" + addStartDate.toLocaleString());
            var eventToAdd = {
                title: $("#addEventName").val(),
                description: $("#addEventDesc").val(),
                start: $("#addEventStartDate").val(),
                end: $("#addEventEndDate").val(),
            };
```

and

```
function selectDate(start, end, allDay) {

$('#addDialog').dialog('open');

//$("#addEventStartDate").text("" + start.toLocaleString());
//$("#addEventEndDate").text("" + end.toLocaleString());

$("#addEventStartDate").val(start.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
$("#addEventEndDate").val(end.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));

//addStartDate = start;
//addEndDate = end;
//globalAllDay = allDay;

//alert(allDay);
```

}

and

```
<div id="addDialog" style="font: 70% 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; margin: 50px;" title="Add Event">
<table cellpadding="0" class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="alignRight">
                name:</td>
            <td class="alignLeft">
                <input id="addEventName" type="text" size="50" /><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="alignRight">
                description:</td>
            <td class="alignLeft">
                <textarea id="addEventDesc" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="alignRight">
                start:</td>
            <td class="alignLeft">
                <input id="addEventStartDate" onchange="start" type="text" size="50" /><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="alignRight">
                end:</td>
            <td class="alignLeft">
                <input id="addEventEndDate" type="text" size="50" /><br /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding your dialog to the dayClick callback of the FullCalendar? Also, you can use any datePicker (like the [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)) in your dialog.

You can use the eventClick callback to edit already created events on the calendar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks ganeshk.
Before using the Datepicker, I wanted to do a test by entering the date manually.
I have the same problem with the update ...
I try, I try without success ...

Comment: I cannot post. I don't understand

Comment: What issues do you get with select and dayClick?

Comment: Unfortunately with either select or dayclick there is no insertion.

Comment: I can not change the date. It reflects only the value of start and end.